# Which is the more efficient way for SELECT onchange?

Tags: jquery, select, onchange

In JQuery, we have two ways for `SELECT` onchage:

### 1. Use the `.change` by specifying the `name`

**HTML:**

```
<select name="a">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('select[name=a]').change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

### 2. Use the `.change` by specifying the `id`

**HTML:**

```
<select id="a">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#a').change(function(){  
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

So, given a smaller or larger list of elements, which one is faster/more efficient when using JQuery?

**What would be the best practice?**

Comment: As every one know, using id is the better choice.. if you have doubt, the go and check your code in jsperf.com

Comment: http://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2

Comment: @Awlad, *why?* Questioner, please define "better".

Comment: If you are fighting for nano seconds, then don't use jQuery...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all there are lots of [**other ways**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to select any element (including a `select` element) in jQuery.
Selecting elements by `id` is always better as it supposed to be unique and gives results faster

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply all the elements then use first.Otherwise use second

Answer (score 0):

1) Id selectors are the fastest
2) Tag name selectors are next fastest
3) Class name selectors with no tag name are the slowest

so you can use id selector.